# If a function is measurable, then so is its absolute value.

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove this proposition:
If a function $f$ is measurable then, its absolute value, $|f|$, is also a measurable function?

Comment: Because $|f|<a$ means $f<a$ or $f>-a$.

Comment: Any composition $g\circ f$ of measurable functions is measurable, so it is enough to observe that the function $g:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto|x|$ is measurable.